# How to call a method that requires a Class<T> object as a parameter?

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a class where  I need the constructor to initialize variable array. I researched on the internet and also stack overflow but now I am stuck on how to call the method. For example how could I call method1 in my example?

```
public class SomeClass<T>{

   public T[] array;

   //Constructor
   public SomeClass()
   {
        Method1(T, 5); //?  error
        Method1(5); //?   error
        Method1(new T().GetType(), 5); //? error
        // HOW CAN I CALL THAT METHOD?

        array = (T[])(new Object[5]); // this gives an error too
   }

   private void Method1(Class<T> type, int size)
   {
       array = (T[])Array.newInstance(type, size);
   }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why `array` is `public`?

Comment: Check this out. It's basically the same question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
class SomeClass<T> {

    private T[] array;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public SomeClass(Class<T> klass, int size) {
        array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(klass, size);
    }

}
```

And to instantiate it:

```
SomeClass<Integer> example = new SomeClass<Integer>(Integer.class, 10);
```

Be aware that the array instantiated is an object array, and all its elements will be  `null` until you explicitly assign them.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to pass the `Class` object representing `T` into the `SomeClass` constructor:

```
public SomeClass(Class<T> clazz)
{
   array = Method1(clazz, 5);
}
```

This is necessary because of [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), which means `T` will have no meaning at runtime ([`Array.newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29) takes a `Class` object representing the array's element type for the same reason).